# How do I convert an array inside an array to a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm new to programming. I am coding with javascript.
I want to convert an array with 3 arrays inside it to one single string and have spaces between each of the different arrays.

I want to turn this:

```
var myArray = [['example'], ['text'], ['hm']]
```

Into this:

```
var myString = 'example text hm'
```

Comment: Don't you mean `myArray = [ 'example','text', 'hm' ];`? What you're typing is not a valid array, not even valid code.

Comment: My bad. I meant to use [] and not {}. I edited the question now.

Comment: use _.flatten in underscorejs,  https://underscorejs.org/#flatten

Comment: What should happen if there’s more than one string in one of the inner arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I think  you want that to be an array with `[]`. If that's the case, this is a good use for [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which will progressively build a concatenated array which you can then join:

```js
let myArray = [['example'], ['text', 'text2'], ['hm']]

let str = myArray.reduce((all, arr) => all.concat(arr)).join(' ')
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Does not work for me for some reason. I get spaces between all the characters. This is what it prints out when I use it in my code: e x a m p l e t e x....etc. I am using p5js, could this have something to do it with not working?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my array so I am gonna try to fix this. But this answered my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for-each loops.

```
myString = "";
for each (row in myArray){
    for each (column in row){
        myString = myString + column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you can use the standard [**`Array.join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). This will invoke the sub-array's [**`.toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method. Usually it returns a string of the items, separated by commas, but Since you've got only a single item in each sub-array, you'll get that item in a string.

```js
const myArray = [['example'], ['text'], ['hm']]

const result = myArray.join(' ')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join them together using [Array.join(' ')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

`const sentence = myArray.join(' ')`

will return `"example text hm"`

The speech marks separated will keep the words separate and stop them joining together. If they are together it will join all the strings `"exampletexthm"`

I would also suggest that you use `const` or `let` instead of `var`. It can cause some issues. [Article to look at](https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70)